# Issue proving whether planes form a prism or are parallel.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the three planes with equations:

$-4x+2y-4z=8$

$5x+2y-z=11$

$2x-y+2z=5$

I was asked to prove whether the set of equations form a sheaf or are parallel. I proceeded to use row reduction and created the two equations:

$-9x+0y-3z=-3$

$9x+0y+3z=21$

So as you can see I have two planes with the same normal direction vector hence showing that they are the same plane i.e. parallel, however my $d$ values on the end aren't the same and when proceeding to sub one into the other I get the inconsistency that $0=18$ which I have been told is proof that they form a prism.

Have I by any chance made an error part way through or is there an error in my understanding?

Comment: These are not lines, these are _planes_...

Comment: My mistake, corrections have been applied.

Comment: Btw first and third planes are parallel as they have same normal vector (i mean direction wise). Third probably intersects the two..

Comment: The 1st and 3rd planes are parallel. (why?) From here it should be easy to deduce how the 3 planes will look like.

Comment: Ok, so the fact the normals are the same show they are the same line, however, what steps would you take to show a set of planes form a prism?

Comment: If those planes were to form a prism there would have to be no parallel planes. But two planes are parallel here, so the set-up is those parallel planes and a third plane cutting both - something like a Z shape.

Comment: I fully understand now, thank you very much.

Comment: They are planes, not lines. And by saving the same (direction wise) normals doesnt equate to them being same. This is because their distance from the origin may be different. If two given planes are already parallel is it possible to insert a 3rd plane s.t. they form a prism?

Comment: One last addition, given the exact same planes but the first is to be given as $-12x+0y-4z=8$ , once I reduce them I seem to get: $9x+3z=d$ and $12x+4z=d$ which means they are parallel and cant form a prism yet the answer states that they do.